# Using Gradle in Android Development

Tags: java, android, gradle, development-environment, android-studio

Im new to android development and ive seen some old tutorials before regarding its development on Eclipse. i recently download the new Android Studio to use for the development. However, i found something new called gradle files that are present in the projects folder along with the normal files that used to be in the project.

Everytime i try to run the app i get the following error:

"
Gradle: 
FAILURE: Could not determine which tasks to execute.
* What went wrong:
Task 'assemble' not found in root project 'SampleProject'.
* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks.
"

Could anyone please explain whats the use of gradle? and do i have to use it while developing android apps?

Thank you

Comment: If you are "new to android development", IMHO you should **NOT** be using Android Studio yet: http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/05/16/android-studio-early-access-preview-and-you.html

Comment: @CommonsWare Why they did release the studio that early, was it a management pressure or what? Using gradle is a great thing in itself but the IntelliJ adds much to the confusion.

Comment: @Alex: "Why they did release the studio that early" -- because there are lots of people who are not "new to android development" who can provide feedback.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ive been developing on eclipse for 2 years now.. so do u still think i shouldnt use Android Studio?

Comment: @CommonsWare plus if not... what do u recommend developing android apps on.. Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA ?

Comment: @Tharwat: "Ive been developing on eclipse for 2 years now.. so do u still think i shouldnt use Android Studio?" -- I would recommend that you stick to Eclipse, probably through the end of 2013. By then, not only will Android Studio be more mature, but you will have more Android experience and will be in better position to deal with any lingering Android Studio issues.

Comment: @CommonsWare therefore i dont need to bother myself with gradle and all this??

Comment: @CommonsWare Android Studio has a lot of nice features as has been presented at Google I/O and yet we are not to use them? What's that a teasing of a kind?

Comment: @Alex yea, the studio is mooooore better than eclipse with nice features.. thats why its sad that we cant use it

Comment: You can use it! You must know that with Eclipse you can make an easier start... w/ android studio you have to try harder... sometimes may its your fault, sometimes not! If you insist, you 'll find it better, even if its in alpha/beta!

Comment: "therefore i dont need to bother myself with gradle and all this?" -- not yet. You can separately experiment with the new Gradle-based build system for command-line work, but that too is a work in progress, and I would not recommend that either for newcomers to Android. "the studio is mooooore better than eclipse with nice features" -- it is also seriously limited in many areas where they have not built out all the functionality yet.

Comment: @Tharwat Yeah, we are told to provide feedback. As if we are at some mayor elections hearing some candidates. They should not have presented it if it's not ready as simple as that.

Comment: They could have presented Gradle only. In fact there were 2 presentations exactly because of that. Gradle rules, Studio is not ready yet. I'm switiching to the command line

Comment: @CommonsWare one more thing.. for the IDEs. Do u recommend using Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA ?? and why? thanks :)

Comment: @Tharwat: Either is fine. Since you already know Eclipse, you might consider starting with that, until you get some Android experience. If, OTOH, you would rather go with IDEA to make moving to Android Studio easier (as Studio is based on IDEA), that would also be reasonable.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you for ur response.. ill definitely consider IDEA,, looks neat

Answer (score 1):

In your top directory file with name `build.gradle` just put:

```
task assemble {}
```

You can see it in known issues [here](http://tools.android.com/knownissues#TOC-Task-assemble-not-found)

Get started with gradle [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide)!

Edit: Android Studio 0.2.1 solves this error: http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio021released

Comment: Thank you.. ill check the links

Comment: Really don't do that. This is just a hack that ignores the fact that the build will not work.

Comment: @Xav I wasn't talking about the cases that the build had errors. I was talking about a bug I read on G+ or somewhere on Android Studio release notes! btw 0.2.1 released, and this I was talking about seems to be fixed: http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio021released PS are you a Google employee? :D

Answer (score 1):

Version 0.2.1 of Studio was just released and provides a better error. You should upgrade and see what happens, but it's likely that your project has another problem that should be fixed instead of randomly adding a task that shouldn't be added.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio is bleeding edge (not yet beta).

For more stable solution use Eclipse with ADT, e.g. ADT-bundle http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

You can develop in Eclipse with ADT and run Gradle build using [Nodeclipse/Enide Gradle for Eclipse](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/tree/master/org.nodeclipse.enide.gradle)
([marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle))

Some screenshots for Gradle for Eclipse:

[image]

[image]